Any old noun class system without chaotic formal/ semantic assignment
When noun class/gender system gets old, the semantic/formal assignment rules of the noun class become more opaque/unreliable because of loanwords and erosion of (derivational) suffixes and etc.
eg. in Swahili, there are lots of loanwords in class 5 and unrelated to the original meaning of the class.
So for old noun class systems, which one still has relatively transparent semantic/formal assignment?

“While actually it is not that common for old languages keep being isolating (eg. Khmer/ Vietnamese)” — What do you mean by this? We don’t have many actually attested cases of isolating languages moving away from an isolating typology. In general, what do you mean by “old languages”? Anything that’s not a creole that developed in recent history?

Isolating languages are less common than most people think but they are bigger than "polysynthetic" langs so people have the misconception it is common. Depending on the definition, no more than <20%, or similar to the proportion of VSO languages in the world. "Polysynthetic" languages are rarer
Let's assume anything that's not a creole in recent history an old language. Most languages have developed some morphology.

While I am not sure if the morphology typology should move cyclically like a clock, the distribution is like a bell curve, languages at both ends are rarer (polysynth. isolat.). Both opposite forces exist so langs today are not all polysynth/ isolat. Similar case with noun class.

While it may well be true that only a relatively small percentage of languages are isolating (I haven’t checked the statistics), they’ve generally remained so quite stably in attested history; apart from Tibetan and a few other examples, in fact, they’ve all stayed isolating throughout their attestation. So when you say that “it is not common for old [isolating] languages [to] keep being isolating”, that’s not correct – out of the old languages which are isolating, it is extremely common for them to remain isolating.

May I suggest, too much has been lost in Editing? Most after Janus Bahs Jacquet's first Comment seems to refer solely to something now deleted…
